# Is there any way to hide a MessageBox?

Tags: vb.net

Is there any way to hide a MessageBox at form load?

I have used `Checkedlistbox`, and already there is a `checkeditems` on load of a `Form2`.

What I want to do is, when I click `Form1` it shows `Form2` with `Checkedlistbox`. My problem is, when I click `Form1`, it show up MessageBox before `Form2`.

Here is my code on vb.net:

On `Form1`:

```
Private Sub cmdSubmitModifyQuant_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSubmitModifyQuant.Click
    Form2.Show()
End Sub
```

On `Form2`:

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    chklstBox1Fill()
End Sub

Private Sub CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.ItemCheck
    If e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked Then
      question = MsgBox("Area you sure you want to remove?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Message")
        If question = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
           'Nevermind
        ElseIf question = MsgBoxResult.No Then
          e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

In my code you can see that i also need to check `checklistbox1`.

Comment: @shad0wk : In VB.NET the forms' class names also provide a default instance, so yes it compiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is probably that inside the `chklstBox1Fill` method you are checking items in your check box list, this causes the event to raise that shows the checkbox. One way to avoid this would be to set a flag to indicate you are populating the list and not show the message box when the flag is set:

```
Private FillingList As Boolean

Private Sub chklstBox1Fill()
    FillingList = True

    'Rest of method here.

    FillingList = False
End Sub

Private Sub CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.ItemCheck
    If FillingList = True Then
        Return
    End If

    If e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked Then
      question = MsgBox("Area you sure you want to remove?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Message")
        If question = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
           'Nevermind
        ElseIf question = MsgBoxResult.No Then
          e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

(Forgive my VB.Net, been several years since I wrote any!)

Comment: This looks right to me, this should theoretically fix the issue

Comment: Ohh. It should fixed my issue. Thanks you, that there are a good guy her in this world. hehehe.

Answer (score 1):

Add a boolean variable that indicates wether your load procedure is complete or not. Doing so will not execute the `CheckedChanged` until the variable is set to True.

```
Dim FormLoaded As Boolean = False

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    chklstBox1Fill()
    FormLoaded = True
End Sub

Private Sub CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.ItemCheck
    If FormLoaded = False Then Return 'Don't execute the rest of the code if it evaluates to False.

    If e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked Then
        question = MsgBox("Area you sure you want to remove?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Message")
        If question = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            'Nevermind
        ElseIf question = MsgBoxResult.No Then
            e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```